# how to make "python setup.py install" install source instead of egg file?

Tags: python, setuptools, egg

I used to run `python setup.py install` in a python project, it will just move the source to `site-packages`, but sometimes it will mv an `egg` file to `site-packages`?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

from setuptools import setup,find_packages

setup(
    name = "ipin_rpc_gen_vector",
    version = "0.0.2",
    packages = find_packages("src"),
    package_dir={"":"src"},
    install_requires=[

    ],
)
```

So what is the difference behind this? When will it install source, when will it just install `egg` file? How can I force install source instead of `egg` file?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? If you want to modify the source code and see what changes, use `python setup.py develop`.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16541150/1959808

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60166477/1959808

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2604694/1959808

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7287318/1959808

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to set the `zip_safe` flag to `False` if you want to avoid the zip (egg) behaviour.

You can read more about it at https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/miscellaneous.html#setting-the-zip-safe-flag.

Also check out https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/keywords.html#new-and-changed-setup-keywords and the `*_package_data` flags (also at: https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/references/keywords.html).

Comment: Numpy uses this python instruction to install : `setup(**metadata)` so I added `zip_safe= False,` in the metadata dict and ran `python setup install` but it still produced an egg file instead of installing the module files in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/`